# Allow Google AdMobs click to unlock features in App - Android

Tags: android, sdk, admob, ads

I was thinking to integrate the Google AdMobs SDK in my free app. Now, I have read the terms of use regarding publishing ads:

> If User is a publisher, User shall not, and shall not authorize or encourage any third party to generate fraudulent impressions of or fraudulent clicks on any advertisement.

But, I'd still like to ask if the following is allowed:

I have a free app with a locked feature (a disabled ListView item). And below it I plan to say the following "Watch 5 ads to unlock this feature". Now, I'm NOT going to be showing any dialog boxes encouraging the user to watch an ad or any other way. And it's completely fine if the user doesn't want to watch an ad; he just doesn't get to unlock that feature. I think this way is more of a passive nudge than actual encouragement. And I plan to stop showing ads as well after the user has watched 5 ads. I don't think that it's fraudulent either.

Considering games like Subway Surfer and Doodle Jump use this method if I want to unlock in-game prizes or start a game from where I left off if I lose, I don't think this should be a problem.

However, I would like to know all your thoughts on this. Is it ok to do this?

Comment: This topic itself is quite interesting for me. However, it may be off-topic here.

Comment: @hata there is a very similar question here too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6540508/allow-user-to-click-on-advertisement-to-unlock-features?rq=1. However, it didn't really answer my query, hence I posted this question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Admob doesn't allows this. but you can check with other third party ad providers like chitika https://chitika.com/mobile if they allow it.

> If User is a publisher, User shall not, and shall not authorize or
>   encourage any third party to generate fraudulent impressions of or
>   fraudulent clicks on any advertisement.

Comment: I'm not generating any fraudulent impressions or fraudulent clicks. And games like Subway Surfers and Doodle Jump do this. Or are they using 3rd Party Ad Providers, in which case, what ad sdk are they using?

Comment: They are using third party ad providers. Google thinks its not a good way to generate impressions or clicks on ads. So its against their policy. But I think all other 3rd party ad providers are comfortable with the 'click ad to unlock' approach.  I don't know which ad provider Subway surfers use, you can search google though.